# Trying to block SAVEAS in Excel 2007, The Cancel=True function does not work

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to use this VBA code to block SAVEAS functionality in ThisWorkBook:

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If (SaveAsUI = True) Then
    MsgBox "here"
    Cancel = SaveAsUI
End If
End Sub
```

I even get the message "here" but the program happily lets me use the SaveAs functionality.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Make sure your  macros Enable or [Create a self-signing certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617344/outlook-not-running-visual-basic-after-restart/31663883#31663883)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, just make sure your code is under `ThisWorkbook`.

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If (SaveAsUI = True) Then
        Cancel = SaveAsUI
    End If
End Sub
```