# Sending Emails with Outlook 2013/Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, email

I currently have a program that queues up emails to send in a spreadsheet and then sends them out through the Outlook application (Excel and Outlook are both 2013 versions).

When I run the program, it goes through without a problem, however when a coworker runs the program they continue to get the prompts that "A program is trying to send a message on your behalf" and then they have to allow or deny each one individually.

I have looked through different methods for addressing this from changing the registry (tried that and it did not change anything) to security settings (still nothing).

Is there a way to address this with VBA?

The current code is:

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body_message As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With olMail

.To = "ADDRESS"

.Subject = "SUBJECT"

.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

.HTMLBody = mail_body_message

'.CC = "EMAIL"
.BCC = ""

.Importance = olImportanceHigh

.ReadReceiptRequested = True

.Send

End With

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can work with [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm), developed by Outlook MVP @Dmitry Streblechenko, which makes it easier to program your solution without triggering such prompts it also makes it easier to program in Outlook. or see if  [SelfCert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617344/outlook-not-running-visual-basic-after-restart/31663883#31663883) will help

Answer (score 0):

From Ron's [site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/security.htm) instead of `.Send`

```
 .Display 
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
 Application.SendKeys "%s"
```

This will just bring up the email and sendkeys Alt-S to send.