# Why did application.reminder stop working?

Tags: vba, outlook

Using Outlook 365.

I needed code to bring Outlook reminders to the front of all other windows. I found this code on the Extend Office website, and entered it into the ThisOutlookSession module:

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
'Updated by ExtendOffice 20180814
Dim xAppointment As AppointmentItem
If Item.Class = olAppointment Then
    Set xAppointment = Item
    MsgBox xAppointment.Subject, 4096 + vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Outlook reminders"
End If
End Sub
```

Last week, it worked fine; whenever a reminder fired, I'd see a Msgbox reiterate its message.

This week, I realized that the Msgbox was no longer popping up. I believe my computer had restarted over the weekend, but that's the only change I can think of. I've tried trapping the code with breakpoints, and as near as I can tell, it's just not running.

I'm not familiar with "ThisOutlookSession", but just to be safe I tried restarting Outlook, and it didn't help. I use two different Desktops in Windows, and I tried running Outlook on each, but that didn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to check the Trust Center settings in Outlook whether VBA macros are allowed to run. Then try to enable macros in Outlook by following:

```
"File"->"Options"->"Trust Center"->"Trust Center Settings..."->"Macro Settings"->"Enable all macros"
```

You may find similar issues posted in the [Outlook Not Running Visual Basic After Restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617344/outlook-not-running-visual-basic-after-restart) and [VB Macro runs successfully at first, but fails after Outlook restart](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/vb-macro-runs-successfully-at-first-but-fails/ff5aedf0-5815-4389-be34-d209b3764c47) posts.

Comment: That seemed to work, which is odd since I had not been getting any "macros not permitted" errors. I'm also wondering if it had something to do with Calendar being my active window rather than Mail.